# Nested functions in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

New to MVC and the API template, familiar with C#.

Plain new WebAPI project with a simple controller. Url path like `/api/Clients/1`, is there a way to sort of nest controllers? Or execute a function in the same controller by following a url path like this: `/api/Clients/1/Sysinfo/typeOf`?

I have a model Client which contains properties which are sysinfo items. /api/Clients/1 returns all the properties of an object Client with the Id of 1. I want only specific items returned with /api/Clients/1/Sysinfo/RAM for example.

---

***@Joachim Rosskopf***
I have tried that approach. It result in a 404. /clients/1/ works. /clients/1/sysinfo does not work.

Using the following routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Sysinfo",
            url: "Clients/{id}/Sysinfo/{type}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Sysinfo", type = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Created a new controller SysinfoController:

```
public class SysinfoController : ApiController
{
    public Sysinfo GetAllSysinfoItems()
    {
        return new Sysinfo { Id = 1, RAM = "1GB" };
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetSysinfoByType(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to handle *both* types of these URLs?

Comment: This link on controllers and routing might help: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing

Comment: Yes indeed. As said I'm new with MVC, maby it is just a logical error. I have a model Client which contains properties which are sysinfo items. /api/Clients/1 returns all the properties of an object Client with the Id of 1. I want only specific items returned with /api/Clients/1/Sysinfo/RAM for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your routing configuration and add special entries for the child routes. It is important to add the most specific route first:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "SysInfoApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/Clients/{id}/Sysinfo/{param}",
       defaults: new { controller = "SysInfo", param = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In the Above example there is a specific route for a `SysInfo` controller, which handles the nested resource. As well as the default route.

The `SysInfo` controller with actions for `GET`-requests could look the following

```
public class SysInfoController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/client/{id}/sysinfo/
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // GET api/client/{id}/sysinfo/{param}
    public string Get(int id, string param)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

I don't know of a method to handle hierarchical ressources in WebApi automatically.

Comment: Added a SysInfoController example to the answer.